# Cannot register QMessageLogContext for message handler

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am currently trying to implement a producer-consumer mechanism to handle log messages using qInstallMessagehandler.

To do this, I define a procuder class MessageHandlers which is creating a consumer thread where messages are written to some trace file:

```
workerThread = new QThread(this);
worker =  new MessageWorker;
worker->moveToThread(workerThread);

qRegisterMetaType<QtMsgType>("QtMsgType");
qRegisterMetaType<QMessageLogContext>("QMessageLogContext");


connect(this, &MessageHandlers::messageEvent, worker, &MessageWorker::messageEvent);
connect(workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);

workerThread->start();
```

MessageHandlers class is emtting a messageEvent signal within the following public function:

```
void MessageHandlers::messageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext & context, const 
QString & message)
{
    emit messageEvent(type, context, message);
}
```

As you can see, I intend to use this public method to install my own message handler using qInstallMessageHandler like this:

```
MessageHandlers globalMessageHandler;
void globalMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext & context, const QString & message) {
    globalMessageHandler.messageOutput(type, context, message);
}
...
qInstallMessageHandler(globalMessageOutput);
```

Unfortunately the compiler si complaining about the registration of QMessageLogContext type:

```
> error: use of deleted function
> 'QMessageLogContext::QMessageLogContext(const QMessageLogContext&)' In
> file included from
> C:\EFApp\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore/qelapsedtimer.h:37:0,
>                  from C:\EFApp\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore/QElapsedTimer:1,
>                  from Config\messagehandlers.h:4,
>                  from Config\messagehandlers.cpp:1: C:\EFApp\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include/QtCore/qlogging.h:58:20:
> note: declared here
>      Q_DISABLE_COPY(QMessageLogContext)
```

And when I comment this registration, the execution is complaining that QMessageLogContext cannot be queued:

```
> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QMessageLogContext'
> (Make sure 'QMessageLogContext' is registered using
> qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Does anybody has a solution to this problem ?

thank you for your help.

Best regards.